# How to speed up Resultant?

Tags: polynomials, algebra

I am experimenting with the polynomials Y and T:

```
i1 = 9; i2 = 4;
Y = Sum[ x^i  y[i], {i, 0, i1}];
T = Sum[ x^i  t[i], {i, 0, i2}];
Timing[Resultant[Y, T, x]]
```

Whith i1=9 , i2= 4 the time is 92.3.
I am interesting for polynomials with i1=10 and i2=8, but after minutes no result is obtained. Is there any idea how to speed up `Resultant`?

Comment: You might experiment with different method option settings.

Comment: Specifically, `Method -> "BezoutMatrix"` seems to be relatively fast for this family of examples.

Comment: In 13.2 it now takes 28.0156 and 1.25 for Method -> "BezoutMatrix".